# How to convert a complete object with its name to a json string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

Hi all I have following class mentioned below that contain nested objects:

```
class Data
    {
        public string Id; 
        pubic Employee employee ;
    }
    class Employee
    {
        pubic Student student;
        public Teacher teacher
    }
    class Student
    {
         age ; 
         id;
    }
    class Teacher
    {
         age ; 
          id;    
    }
I want to fetch the employee data from my object but in JSON format like

 { 
"Employee":{
         "Student":{id:0},
         "Teacher" :{id:0}
    }}
```

I used  JsonConvert.Serialize(Data.employee);  but it converted my JSON to this

```
{ 
    {
             "Student":{id:0},
             "Teacher" :{id:0}
    } 

}
```

anyone have any better solution?

Comment: Update your class definitions and then you need to serialize the `Data` object you have. Why couldn't you do: `JsonConvert.Serialize(Data);`? Another option provided by [Jonesopolis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67420586/1797425) would work as well. Another thing worth mentioning, the code provided is invalid. Also you may want to use properties and not fields, for example in `Employee` class: `pubic Student student;` => `public Student student { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to tweak your object definition to get it to serialize the way you want.  Try wrapping it in an anonymous object:

```
JsonConvert.Serialize(new { Employee = Data.employee});
```